# How does Boost Serialization make use of operator& to implement archiving / serialization?

Tags: c++, boost

How does Boost Serialization work?

In particular, Boost Serialization appears to make use of `operator &`.

How is it that defining a function like the following

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & degrees;
    ar & minutes;
    ar & seconds;
}
```

in combination with `friend class boost::serialization::access;`

permits the following functions to be called?

```
std::ofstream ofs("filename");
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
oa << g;
```

Examples taken from the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have `boost::serialization::access` acting as a place that's been friended by relevant types, which will expose `serialise` to the relevant parties.

Something like:

```
namespace boost::archive {

class access {
protected:
    template <typename T, typename Archive>
    void serialise(T & t, Archive & a, int version) {
        t.serialise(a, version);
    }
};

}
```

The archive types will inherit from `boost::serialization::access`, and also implement various `operator &`, including a catch-all template that calls `serialise`. E.g. for writing to a `std::ostream`

```
namespace boost::archive {

class oarchive : access {
public:
    void operator &(int i) { os << i; }
    /* other overloads for things that you can os << into */
    template <typename T>
    void operator &(T & t) { serialise(t, *this, version); }
private:
    std::ostream & os;
    int version = /* determine version somehow */;
}

}
```

Or for reading from a `std::istream`

```
namespace boost::archive {

class iarchive : access {
public:
    void operator &(int i) { is >> i; }
    /* other overloads for things that you can is >> out of */
    template <typename T>
    void operator &(T & t) { serialise(t, *this, version); }
private:
    std::istream & is;
    int version = /* determine version somehow */;
}

}
```

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused. If `degrees` is of type `int`, doesn't this mean `T=int` and the serialize function tries to call `degrees.serialize(a, version)` ?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant the archive can overload operator for primitive type operands as well: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0654e4dd4cdaeaf5

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant the non-template overload is preferred, see [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function)